# How to start and stop virtual machines from custom website

Tags: virtual-machine

I’m trying to figure out how to run vms from a website.

For example like hackthebox where you can start, stop and reset vms from the website. No need for rdp or anything.

What kind of frameworks would be needed to control them from a custom website?

Comment: OpenStack would be one possibility.  VMware another.

Comment: I can only find information to host websites from the open stack vm…. Any information on how to control a list of vms from a custom website? Thanks for responding

Comment: To control the VMs from a custom website, your VMs must be managed by some kind of infrastructure.  What infrastructure are you using to manage your VMs?  (If you don't yet know the details of the VM managemen infrastructure, then designing the website is premature.  And obviously, we can't answer your question either.)

Comment: I just read up on openstack and will use that infrastructure for management, which I will start setting up. And thank you. I have no idea about this but would like to learn

Comment: Well OpenStack has a client libraries in Python and Java that you can use to send management requests to the OpenStack services to tell them to start and stop VMs.  Your custom website can use those libraries.

Comment: You can find Openstack training courses and training material using Google search.

Comment: Anyway we can chat more somewhere else about high level architecture  design for what I’m trying to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240700/discussion-between-levi-and-stephen-c).